# Connecting an external switch to my circuit

Tags: power-supply, power, switches, schematics, kicad

I'm pretty new to electronics and kicad.
I would like to understand how to add a physical switch to my circuit using molex connection.

I'm adding my initial schema.
[image]

Comment: please explain what you do not understand about switches

Comment: I have the connector J1, It is a molex connector.
I wanted to know if I connected it correctly so i would be able to connect a physical switch through J1.
I want to control the current between "BatteryVin" to "Switch" so it won't be on all the time.

Comment: a switch is basically the same as touching the two wires together .... think about this, take `BatteryVin` wire in one hand and the `Switch` wire in the other hand and touch them together ... that is what a switch does

Comment: Yes, so what I did is ok?
if one end is connected to "BatteryVin" and the other end is connected
to "Switch", then I connect my physical switch to "1,2" and it will make sure that if the switch is off then no current will flow from "BatteryVin" to "Switch"?
or should I change something?

Comment: that is correct, nothing to change .... make sure that the switch is rated for the voltage and current that will be switched ... AC and DC ratings are not interchangeable ... for example, a switch could be rated for 10 A AC and only 3 A DC

Answer (score 0):

KiCad is not a system design program. Which means it does not care what you connect externally to the pcb but only which things are soldered to the pcb to do so. There are a lot of options how to connect external stuff in general https://forum.kicad.info/t/how-to-connect-a-wire-to-the-pcb/18262

---

You can however still use KiCad to also document what is externally. Either by use of general graphics, by use of text comments or by placing symbols and wires but excluding the symbols from being part of the netlist via adding "#" in front of the reference designator.